# Do you want to go see or watch some birds?

Tags: word-choice

> 8 [WATCH](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/see) [transitive] **to watch a television programme, play,
>   film etc**
>
> *Did you see that programme on monkeys last night?*
>
> *We’re going to see ‘Romeo and Juliet’ tonight.*

---

> 1 [LOOK](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/watch) [intransitive, transitive] **to look at someone or
>   something for a period of time, paying attention to what is
>   happening**
>
> Do you mind if I watch?
>
> We sat and watched the sunset.
>
> watch carefully/closely/intently etc
>
> He watched helplessly as Paula fell into the icy water.
>
> Watch carefully. You may learn something.
>
> watch (somebody/something) with interest/amusement/delight etc
>
> Harriet watched him with interest.
>
> watch somebody/something do/doing something
>
> I watched him go, then went home.
>
> Ruth could not bear to watch her parents arguing.
>
> watch to do something
>
> I watched to see how he’d react.
>
> watch television/a film etc
>
> The debate was watched by 97 million viewers.
>
> Most parents don’t know what their kids are watching on TV.
>
> watch what/how/when etc
>
> It’s useful to watch how other pilots handle the glider.

So, how do native speakers say, for example, when a dad talks to his little child?:

Do you want to go **see** or **watch** some birds?

Answer (score 1):

Both could be used depending on context. The key difference is that watching something takes place over a period of time and that seeing something can take place instantaneously.

> > Do you want to go watch some birds?

Could mean "Would you like to sit for a while looking at birds?"

> > Do you want to go see some birds?

Could mean "There are some interesting-looking birds over there, would you like to look at them before they fly away?"

Both of these are completely reasonable English sentences. A young child would probably be more interested in seeing some birds and then doing something else, and wouldn't have the patience to stay and watch them, but that's a question for another site.

---

Now, there are some situations where "see" and "watch" are more or less interchangeable, including some given in examples in this question.

> > Did you see that programme on monkeys last night?
> >
> > The debate was watched by 97 million viewers.

In both of these, "see" can be exchanged with "watch," and vice-versa, without changing the meaning. In general, however, "see" emphasizes that something happened at all, while "watch" emphasizes that it took place over a period of time.